# First time logging into Linux N1

Tags: linux-kernel

I have been trying to access Linux N1 (1.00.3001), Kernel 4.2.3 but this kernel is asking me for

```
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I know I'm supposed to type `startx` or `X` now, but I get

```
-bash: root: command not found error.
```

What should I type to get rid of this error and enter the GUI mode?

Comment: A server distribution is meant to be run without GUI, that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: GUI is not runnable under root user even on systems that support it. So, just go ahead and start using most powerful console interface.

Answer (score 0):

So what distribution are you using exactly? I don't find anything about "N1 Linux" on the web.

I assume that you have bought a notebook with a preinstalled Linux version. The big companys mostly use "Linpus Linux" in this case.

Linpus comes without GUI, so you either install the needed packages manually or, which is the better solution afaik, go for another distro:

[Distrowatch](https://distrowatch.com/?language=EN)